# How to resolve Concurrency Issue while updating document in Marklogic DB

Tags: java, marklogic

I am trying to use optimistic locking for resolving concurrency issue using DocumentDescriptor for a document when I update a document in Marklogic database. But when I am updating documents in Batch using  DataMovementManager/ WriteBatcher how can I use DocumentDescriptor or optimistic locking here ?

```
 DataMovementManager dataMovementManager = client.newDataMovementManager();
        WriteBatcher writeBatcher = dataMovementManager.newWriteBatcher();
writeBatcher.add("Test.xml");``

    writeBatcher.flushAndWait();
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more, or better - show some code that demonstrates how you are getting the documents that you are modifying and why you want to use a DocumentDescriptor?